# Python Socket HTTP Proxy: Forwarding Requests

Tags: python, sockets, http, proxy, python-requests

I'm currently trying to develop a simple python socket HTTP proxy. I'm at the step where I can receive the data in this format:

> `b'GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'`

I'm currently trying to send this back to the browser to forward all the recieved data just for the flexiblity of Python and the experience but it's not really working. Below is how I try to send the data:

```
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.connect((hst, 80))
s1.sendall(data)
print("Request sent?")
conn.sendall(data)
```

Basically I open a new socket to send the recieved request back to the browser. In the browser it just stalls and loads indefiently. I was thinking this could be related to SSL but the website I'm testing this on is HTTP not HTTPS. I'm not sure where to go from here. Please just give me pointers or a solution for all that matters. I'm getting really bored in this quarentine.

Thanks for your time!

[Pastebin of horrible code if needed.](https://pastebin.com/WUcamhQ5)

Comment: The response has to actually adhere to the HTTP protocol but yours don't. I recommend that you at least read [Wikipedia: HTTP - Example session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session) to get a feeling of how a proper HTTP response should look like. Note that the example there is very simply and that in reality HTTP might be more complex. For more please see the actual HTTP standard - that's what standards are for.

Comment: Are you trying to write back the request you got from the client ? In that case, your browser should be showing invalid http response instead of hanging there indefinitely.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the HTTP request to be sent as if the browser went to the webpage. I see how the HTTP should look in the Wikipedia page sent, is there a way I should format it? How do I turn the raw data that I get into the correct HTTP response so that it can be sent correctly?